# Change % gauge chart to exact value in c3.js

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I am trying to change the units of a gauge chart. Instead of showing the % value by default, I would like to show the exact value. I looked for that in the documentation but it is incomplete and I am not sure which value I should put in the code to change it.

```
var chart = c3.generate({
bindto: "#chart",
data: {
    columns: [
        ['data', 15.0]
    ],
    type: 'gauge',
},
gauge: {
    min: 50,
    max: 100,
    units: '%' //I want to change that
}
});
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I am answering myself. To get the exact value and not the % one in a gauge chart, it is necessary to add this lines:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: "#chart",
    data: {
    columns: [
        ['data', 15.0]
     ],
    type: 'gauge',
    },
    gauge: {
    label:{
    format: function(value, ratio){
      return value; //returning here the value and not the ratio
      },
    },
    min: 50,
    max: 100,
    units: '%' //this is only the text for the label
    }
});
```

Comment: the [commentted code](http://c3js.org/samples/chart_gauge.html) shows `gauge.label.format`. also see [documentation](http://c3js.org/reference.html#gauge-label-format).