# Show percentage value greater than 100 in c3 gauge chart

Tags: d3.js, charts, data-visualization, c3.js

[image]
I want to show a chart for current progress using C3.js library like this.
But there is no support for radial progress in C3.js
I tried using gauge chart http://c3js.org/samples/chart_gauge.html
but for all values greater than 100% it shows 100% only.
Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/iamaditya/pmgyx58t/

```
var chart1 = c3.generate({
bindto: '#test',
data: {
    columns: [ ['data', 150] ],
    type: 'gauge'
}
```

})

Is there any way I can do that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do what you want. I suggest you first calculate the maximum percentage you need just before displaying the graph (use the data that you are about to display to make this calculation) then use that number as the maximum... and set the labelling function.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jzwolak/Lj0qg693/

Here's the relevant code... I did change the hard coded max from the fiddle to a function to reflect my first suggestion.

```
var chart1 = c3.generate({
  bindto: '#test',
  data: {
    columns: [
      ['data', 150]
    ],
    type: 'gauge'
  },
  gauge: {
    label: {
      format: function(value, ratio) {
        return value; //returning here the value and not the ratio
      },
    },
    min: 0,
    max: calcMaxFromCurrentData(),
    units: '%' //this is only the text for the label
  }
})
```

My answer is a modified version of the SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27026308/361855

Answer (score 0):

You can change the max value using the gauge object in the generate method:

```
var chart1 = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#test',
    data: {
        columns: [ ['data', 150] ],
        type: 'gauge'        
    }, 
    gauge: {
        max: 200
    }
})
```

I've updated your fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/pmgyx58t/1/

Comment: Thanks for the comment but for real-life data like sales targets, profit etc max value may vary & it won't be feasible to show figures more than 100% in range 0-100. What I mean is that there must some way to even show 150% like we can do in radial progress.

Comment: I'm not too sure you'll be able to achieve that using the gauge chart. What would you expect to display if it was 200%? I guess you could show two rings, you might need to extend c3 to support what you are looking for as I don't think it'll come out of the box. I'll take a look for you though

Comment: Exactly it should have multiple arcs in case of more than 100%. How can I extend the C3 library? Is there any documentation for that?

Comment: their github is here: https://github.com/c3js/c3 so you could fork it and make the changes you need to support multiple rings, you could then do a pull request then they could include your changes in their next release, or you can create a release for your fork and use it. You could install it via npm, or if you are referencing a single js file for c3, you can build your modified version and then reference the outputted file.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will look into that.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
   data: {
        columns: [ ['data', 150] ],
        type: 'gauge'
    }
```

to

```
data: {
    columns: [ ['data', yScale(150)] ],
    type: 'gauge'
}
```

add this function but you must deffine your data min max cos pie chart only append on percentage that mean 0 - 100

```js
var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                  .domain([100,500])//min max your data
                  .range([0,100])// this fix falue mean this is a percentage you must define your data min max and convert it
     
     console.log(yScale(150))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```